# Get only certain fields of related object in Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have such models in Django:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(...)
    email=models.EmailField(...)
    photo=...
    <other fields>

class Comment(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

I have a function that receives Comment object and needs just name and email fields to send email (it is just example, obvious)

```
def sendEmail(comment):
    name, email=comment.user.name, comment.user.email
```

In implementation presented above, Django will fetch all fields of related object User (something roughly equal to `select * from users where id=comment.user_id`)
Using values_list I can fetch just needed fields:

`Users.objects.filter(id=comment.user_id).values_list('name', 'email')`

but values_list only applicable to QuerySet object, not to model instance.
My question is: is there any way to do the same thing using only "comment" object?
It must be equal to
`select name, email from users where id=comment.user_id` by complexity (I don't want to transfer a lot of data stored in some fields over network when I don't need it)

Comment: So in short, you would like the `ForeignKey` to fetch the related object only partially without the need for an *explicit* queryset?

Comment: @dhke, yes, exactly

Comment: Frankly: Hand  `Comment` a property that returns the result from the above query. Other solutions I come up with all end up in `contribute_to_class()` with a custom [ForwardManyToOneDescriptor](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8db6a6c0a1c73bf08e71e00d4ab8c4af3c5f0cb8/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L78) and that's just overkill.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to have comments with some additional user data, without having to retrieve whole `User` objects I believe it's better to fetch additional data when you fetch the comments:

```
Comment.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('user__name', 'user__email')
```

Obviously you can fetch other useful `Comment` fields.

OR:

```
Comment.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(author_name=F('user__name'),\ 
                                           author_email=F('user__email'))
```

This still uses the `QuerySet` API, but both approaches allow you to span relationships to get additional data without extra queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
Users.objects.filter(id=comment.user_id).values_list('name', 'email').get()
```

That should do

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset = ModelName.objects.filter().only('realed_obj__field1', 'related_obj__field2')
```

Answer (score 0):

> It must be equal to `select name, email from users where id=comment.user_id` by complexity.

What is really equivalent to this query is what you already have:

```
Users.objects.filter(id=comment.user_id).values_list('name', 'email')
```

> ... but `values_list` only applicable to `QuerySet` object, not to model instance.

That is absolutely right. but what you need to consider is that once you have this queryset you can get the first element because with one user id there will just be one user:

```
name, email = Users.objects.filter(id=comment.user_id).values_list('name', 'email').first()
```

Comment: Using `first` and tuple expansion together is a bad idea... if nothing matches then you'll get an error because it can't split `None` into two parts.